# How to buy Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

In the old days we went to a local store and hoped that your Software available on a DVD in the correct language. Can Windows 8 be bought over the internet (which price then) and how does it work?

Comment: what price for where?

Comment: You should check http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/ for more information.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett the price of the windows 8 depends on when you have bought windows 7.

Comment: @gotqn - Actually it doesn't.  It actually depends if you have purchased a new pc within a certain timeframe, otherwise, any version of Windows allows you to purchase it at a reduce price ( download only ) or retail ( higher then the download price but still cheaper for awhile ) then the retail price will be in 2013 and beyond.  Furthermore you can buy the System Builder ( OEM ) today if you  want at the normal price.  The cheaper version will be Upgrade which requires a previous version no matter when you purchase it, the OEM won't require a previous version, but will be the same price as now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can buy it from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=windows%208).
- You can buy it from [Microsoft Store Online](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro?Icid=Homepage_4_Up_Win8_Pro_10_26).
- You can buy it from local retailers as soon as they have the packed upgrade CDs.
  Just follow any of the links above for more details on prices.

Non upgrade costs: 99.99$ / 139.99$

Upgrade costs: 39.99$ / 69.99$

Answer (score 2):

You can buy windows online as a download, depending on your region.

See here for the list of countries: [Windows 8 Terms and Conditions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions)

---

In my region I can get it from microsoft from here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_DIS_ShopHP_FPP_Light

Clicking the download button on that link will download the Windows Upgrade Assistent which will walk you through the process of upgrading an existing windows installation.

---

Note that if you have purchased a PC with Windows 7 (or Windows 7 on its own) recently, you may be able to get the upgrade free from the place you bought it, or from windows via the [Windows Upgrade Offer](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com/)

---

If you don't own a version of windows you need the System Builder version, for example from here:

[Windows 8 System Builder DVD 64-Bit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094NY3R0)