# Where can I buy Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to buy Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/493139/how-to-buy-windows-8)

Windows 8 has been released today but I cannot find any place where I can buy and download a copy. The only Microsoft offer I found is this page but it is for upgrades only.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/download-shop

Does anyone know where I can buy/download windows 8 so I can do a clean install?

Comment: But why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

You want the System Builder version, as detailed in this question:

[How to make a Windows 8 clean install without prior Windows installation or key?](https://superuser.com/questions/493142/how-to-make-a-windows-8-clean-install-without-prior-windows-installation-or-key)

Here it is for example on amazon: http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094NXBZ0